# can not import in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I exported database, from mysql workbench, and it is in local disk C, and then delete the database, from MySQL workbench, and then imported database(which I exported previously, in this case ui.sql) and original database name is hibernatedb (which I deleted from MySQL workbench), so now the error is unknown database, how can I import this?[this is commands of import.[this is exported database in local disk C.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Y7t.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the "Include Create Schema" option in the Data Export wizard is disabled. I suspect you left it disabled, so your generated SQL lacks a query to create your database. In other words, you need to create your hibernatedb database. So, you might add "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `hibernatedb`; USE `hibernatedb`;" on top of ui.sql.